# Change menu header image using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So in onCreate I try to change the image from a navigation view header with another one that I can access via an url. I am using an AsyncTask to do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sidebar_menu);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        User u = MainProvider.sharedInstance().getCurrentUser(this);
        TextView usernameText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);

        ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        String profilePictureUrl = u.getSettings().get("profile_picture").getAsString();
        new convertUrlToBitmap().execute(profilePictureUrl);
        profilePicture.setImageBitmap();
    }
```

And my AsyncTask looks like this:

```
class convertUrlToBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            connection.disconnect();
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed

    }
}
```

What I fail to understand is how to use what I get from my task in the setImageBitmap method:

```
profilePicture.setImageBitmap()
```

Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: convertUrlToBitmap is a separate class or just its inside you Activity..?

Comment: Inside my activity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `profilePicture` as local variable add it as Global variable, and in on `onPostExecute`, just set the Bitmap

Your Main Activity

```
private ImageView profilePicture

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sidebar_menu);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    User u = MainProvider.sharedInstance().getCurrentUser(this);
    TextView usernameText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);

    profilePicture = (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    String profilePictureUrl = u.getSettings().get("profile_picture").getAsString();
    new convertUrlToBitmap().execute(profilePictureUrl);
    profilePicture.setImageBitmap();
}
```

Your on PostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    // TODO: check this.exception
    // TODO: do something with the feed
    profilePicture.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
}
```

Note:
Instead of downloading using `HttpURLConnection`  you can use `Glide` lib, Official Android doc also recommended to use `Glide`

Using Glide you can use like this,

```
Glide.with(this).load(profilePictureUrl).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user).into(profilePicture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface callback with a method onBitmapLoaded, and use this interface as a param of your AsyncTask.

But know that for image loading you can use third party libraryies like Picasso or Glide that are exactly design for asynchronous image fetching, very well documented and easy to use.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Set any views in postExecute method of asynctask as it runs in UI thread. You already return bitmap in post execute method so you just need to make this change. This is provided that your asynctask is in your activity.

```
class convertUrlToBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private Exception exception;

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        connection.disconnect();
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    // TODO: check this.exception
    // TODO: do something with the feed

        profilePicture.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)

}
```

}

Another very easy and efficient solution is using Picasso or Glide library since you already have image url. It will reduce your work creating asynctask. Just add this library in your gradle.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and make this change in your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sidebar_menu);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    User u = MainProvider.sharedInstance().getCurrentUser(this);
    TextView usernameText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);

    ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    String profilePictureUrl = u.getSettings().get("profile_picture").getAsString();
    Picasso.with(this)
        .load(profilePictureUrl)
        .placeHolder(defaultPicId) //this image will display until your result image is ready
        .error(defaultErrorPicId) //this image will display in case  of error.
        .into(profilePicture)
}
```

I highly recommend using picasso library in your case.